Настройка BitrixVM 9.0.0 и xdebug
Пытаюсь настроить xdebug в связке с BitrixVM 9.0.0
Развернул локально проект (Корпортал Битрикс24) - всё нормально работает
Хочу настроить себе отладчик xdebug в связке с PHP Storm 2021.3
Данные сервера:
Операционная система - CentOS
PHP: 7.4.33
Настройки /etc/php.d/15-xdebug.ini:
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.216.130
xdebug.client_host=192.168.216.130
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.client_port = 9000
xdebug.start_with_request = "yes"
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1

192.168.216.130 - адрес, который дала сама виртуальная машина битрикс. Проект в браузере открывается по этому адресу
В PHPStorm трубка стоит в режиме прослушивания. Я создал тестовый скрипт в корне проекта:
<?php
$test = '123';
phpinfo();
?>

Поставил точку останова на строке $test = '123';
Запускаю в браузере этот скрипт, но он не останавливается в этойточке, а просто полностью отрабатывает и всё.
Помогите пожалуйста, кто с таким сталкивался, как правильно настроить xdebug на стороне BitrixVM и на стороне PHPStorm, чтобы он заработал?
Скриншоты прикрепил.




